# (Android & Firebase) Cannot resolve symbol 'dataSnapshot'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I don't know why **dataSnapshot** doesn't work.

> symbol: variable dataSnapshot

```
private void Startplaylist(String mood) {
        DatabaseReference p_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Playlist");
        //DatabaseReference p_music = (DatabaseReference) p_ref.child("Playlist_Mood").equalTo(mood);
        p_ref.child("Playlist_ID").equalTo(0).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                music_id = dataSnapshot.getValue("Playlist_Id"); // Problem HERE!!
                str_musictitle.setText(music_id);
                    //music_id = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    //str_musictitle.setText(music_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

This is my **build.gradle(Module: app)** code.

```
dependencies {
    /-- fire storage--/
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I searched hard and looked for a solution, but I couldn't solve it, so I asked a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because please dont use screenshots of code, format it using the WYSIWYG

Comment: Shouldn't it be just snapshot?

Comment: Just a simple typo. The var definition is `snapshot` here `(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)` and you're using `snapShot` here `music_id = dataSnapshot` thereafter. Closing due to typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing that `dataSnapshot` in red because there is no such object present in your code. Most likely you should use the `snapshot` object that is present as an argument. So please change the following line of code:

```
music_id = dataSnapshot.getValue("Playlist_Id");
```

To:

```
music_id = snapshot.getValue("Playlist_Id");
```